# Lightweight X window library

Tags: x11

I'm wanting to port a windows program I'm working on to linux. It entirely uses d3d11 to draw it output so I'll need to write an opengl alternative. That's fine. But I need to create a window and a few basic operations like resizing, setting fullscreen, getting notified of user keyboard and mouse input, and close and resize notification.

I won't require any child windows, or controls as everything is drawn by opengl.

So what is an appropriate way to do this? I looked at raw Xlib but it seems quite low level. I'm prepared to learn it but all the examples seem really old so I'm not sure if it's still the best way, plus will doing that work with whatever environment the user had (kde, gnome etc...)?

I could use qt, kde etc, but they are far, far more sophisiticated than I need for this so introduce a large dependency that I'd rather avoid if possible.

So, is Xlib an appropriate technology for this, or is there some other lightweight library I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). It's pretty much the standard choice for applications like yours.

Comment: While that technically would work, and is a good answer, I really wanted something I could link statically into my program and which only incorporated the functionallity I needed. Plus I'm not entirely sure that an lgpl license meets my needs. It's a good answer though and one I'll certainly look into.

Comment: @JohnB I think SDL suits your needs very well. The requirement that you want to link statically is somewhat surprising, the alternatives you mentioned (Qt etc) are certainly not something you'd link statically very often. SDL is tiny (the Win32 DLL is ~140 *KB*) so it really is lightweight. The license should be fine, that's what LGPL is for. :)

Comment: I certainly intend to try it and think it might well work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) could suit your needs.